# How to tackle connect variable if we include many files into a single file

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a page into which I fetch header, footer etc from different files. Each sub file needs to use some php.
Currently what I am doing is that I am using

```
mysql_connect(servername,username,password);
```

in every subfile. Is there any shorter format for doing that so that I could connect only in the main file and the subfiles get connected automatically?

Comment: PHP's `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  There are [alternatives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) that are both supported and [much safer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/132382).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put that code at the top of the `header` file...

Otherwise you could look into automatic append and prepend:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-automatically-append-prepend/

I have never tried using it, seems a little dodgy to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're including files, and include just inserts the file's code into wherever the `include` statement is, you can connect at the top of your main file and all of the other files should be able to work with it just fine.